# tcsh: sequence command

Tags: tcsh

How to change dir from output of previous 2 cmd ?
In `bash` it would be something like:

```
cd $(whereis evince | awk '{print $2}')
```

I need this in `tcsh`
Just can't find examples. Reading man wasn't helpful.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tcsh` uses backticks :

```
cd `whereis evince | awk '{print $2}'`
```